# copy large Nvarchar(max) table from one db to another

Tags: sql, ssis, ssis-2008

I have a table with more then 60 fields of Nvarchar(max) and i need to copy the table to another db with ssis.

i disabled all the index's and it's helped a bit, but still it's take a lot of time to copy all the table (more then 1M rows) - it's take an hour for this moment.

Do anyone have an idea to make it run faster?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the fastest way to load large data is to use bulk insert.  This is usually done from a flat file, so you have to export the data to a file first, before performing the bulk insert.

If you don't like the flat file approach, the alternative is to write a CLR routine. You can use a SqlDataReader to read from table storing the data in a DataTable and then using SqlBulkCopy to do the bulk insert.  The advantage of this approach is that you can use a buffer system to limit the memory required.  The SqlDataReader is memory efficient, it reads lines as required and then drops them from memory, the DataTable is not.  So you set yourself a limit, say 10,000 rows, and whenever the DataTable hits this limit you perform SqlBulkCopy and delete the existing rows in the DataTable and carry on with the next batch.